# Changing way r.cost and r.drain modules work?

Tags: grass-gis, cost-path, shortest-path

Look at the picture #1. This is my cost surface raster that has only 2 values. Area restricted for path to cross (red one) and area that is free to go (yellow one). As I need it and as I undestand how it is should work, my least cost path shoul be look like a straight line between two points for most of a time. Practically I have what you can see on picture #2 (performed by *r.drain*). Cumulative cost gained by using *r.cost* module showed on picture #3. And to be more clear, what I want to get is showed on picture #4.
Basicaly I just need to get minimum distance beetween two points.

[image: Pictures that are showing the problem subject]

Is there a way to reach the goal?

Comment: This is how costdistance works on a square-celled raster, because there are only eight local directions towards nearest neighbors. To do any better, you would have to write your own algorithm that accounts for more-distant neighbors.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem just recently.

And I've found a way of getting a better path. In my case, I was trying to visualise the effect of having the Panama and Suez canals.

My suggestion isn't going to help you find the exact distance, however - but it will trace a more realistic minimum cost path which should be closer in length to the real optimum.

You've got a uniform cost value for the sea, and a high cost value for land. So far, so good.

When I did the least-cost path from Bristol, England to Sydney in Australia, the suggested path hugged the west coast of Africa, before rounding the cape and going in a straight line (line shown in red)

[image]

As whuber hinted at, this is caused by lots of local optimums not adding up to a global optimum.

The way I did it was to add peturbation, so that some randomness comes into play.

- add a random value raster in SAGA GIS ('Random field'), the same size as my cost surface
- and add this to my cost raster (Grid Sum in SAGA)
- trace the least cost route on the noisy raster.

In my case I added a value between 0 and 10, as I wasn't bothered about the actual distance, just a better path. I find uniform works better than guassian. I'm using 9999 as the land cost.

Now, with the randomised cost surface, I find the shortest path now crosses diagonally, rather than hugging coastlines. The orange route is the one based on the noisy raster...

[image]

In my case I'm using a python script (from the gdal python cookbook) to do the least-cost tracing as a raster, so you mileage may vary depending on how you do the point to point path tracing (I can't get r.drain to work at the moment with QGIS).

Comment: That sounds very interesting! Also, might work for me aswell. I'm going to try this. Will keep you in touch. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remain in the GRASS GIS context, there are a number of options to generate these "noise" maps, too. See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/keywords.html#random